# RedirectToAction causes unwanted results with Request.UrlReferrer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, httpwebrequest, redirecttoaction

So, if a user is viewing page A, there is a link to page B.  That link is clicked.  Page B needs a user to be authenticated, so if they are not, I use RedirectToAction to send the user to the Login page inside page B's action.  But, when I try to get the previous page from Request.UrlReferrer, I get the URL for page A.  How can I get the URL for page B instead?

Comment: You need to show your code, but in any case why are you not just using the `[Authorize]` attribute on the method that renders Page B?

Comment: The code is explained above.  All it would be is an if statement followed by a RedirectToAction("Login", "Accounts");